# Rock Paper Scissors in Python.... do i use chained or nested conditional to get this to run?

Tags: python-2.6

Am i supposed to create a chained conditional or nested?

```
player1 = raw_input ("?")
player2 = raw_input ("?")

if (player1 == 'rock' and player2 == 'scissors'):
   print "Player 1 wins."

elif (player1 == 'rock' and player2 == 'rock'):
   print "Tie"

elif (player1 == 'scissors' and player2 == 'paper'):
   print "Player 1 wins."

elif (player2 == 'scissors' and player2 == 'scissors'):
   print "Tie"

elif (player1 == 'paper' and player2 == 'paper'):
   print "Tie"

elif (player1 == 'paper' and player2 == 'scissors'):
   print "Player 2 wins."

elif (player1 == 'rock'and player2 == 'paper'):
   print "Player 2 wins."

elif (player1 == 'paper' and player2 == 'rock'):
   print "Player 2 wins."

elif (player1 == 'scissors' and player2 == 'rock'):
    print "Player 2 wins."
else:
   print "This is not a valid object selection."
```

Answer (score 0):

The question should probably be migrated to [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/), but until then, I'll put my answer here...

Instead of making all those checks nested *or* chained, you can use `or` to combine different conditions yielding the same result, e.g. one player winning. Also, the check whether player 1 wins over player 2 is the same as the other way around, so you can put this into a function.

This will make you code shorter, more readable and easier to maintain.

```
ROCK, PAPER, SCISSORS = "rock", "paper", "scissors"

def valid(s):
    """ s is a valid input """
    return s in [ROCK, PAPER, SCISSORS]

def wins(p1, p2):
    """ p1 wins over p2 """
    return (p1 == ROCK and p2 == SCISSORS or
            p1 == SCISSORS and p2 == PAPER or
            p1 == PAPER and p2 == ROCK)

player1 = raw_input ("Player 1: ").strip().lower()
player2 = raw_input ("Player 2: ").strip().lower()
if valid(player1) and valid(player2):
    if wins(player1, player2):
        print "Player 1 wins."
    elif wins(player2, player1):
        print "Player 2 wins."
    else:
        print "Tie."
else:
    print "This is not a valid object selection."
```